# Is there a NoScript alternative for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

I love using Google Chrome, but I don't like visiting sites that have embedded ads/pages that could have malicious JavaScript.  Is there something like the Firefox extension, [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript), for Google Chrome?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you by default disable scripting on all websites? How does that impact your browsing experience?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma - Sometimes some scripts have to be enabled for functionality but overall, much cleaner and marketing-BS-free.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out Privoxy. Lifehacker has a [great guide](http://lifehacker.com/5046529/how-to-block-ads-in-google-chrome) on how to set it up.

Privoxy supports stripping ads, Javascript and nasty pieces of HTML, as well as string-replacement for any web browser. I have used it in the past and I did not notice a speed difference.

Comment: This fails to answer the question, which is no, there is no proper extension support for Chrome.

Comment: At the time of writing, there was no extension support for Chrome, so this was, IMO, the best way to achieve similar functionality. This answer was found to solve the problem that Steve Wright was having, so it DOES answer the question.

Comment: As of now, there is HTTP Switchboard ([Chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-switchboard/mghdpehejfekicfjcdbfofhcmnjhgaag) or on [github](https://github.com/gorhill/httpswitchboard)).

Answer (score 21):

[ScriptSafe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf) has come out recently, and beats NotScripts.

> A simple extension that brings some of NoScript's functionality to Chrome while emphasizing simplicity and intuitiveness (no affiliation to NoScript):
>
> - whitelisting/blacklisting functionality and granular control
> - actually speeds up browsing because it removes a lot of unwanted content
> - ability to remove `<SCRIPT>, <OBJECT>, <EMBED>, <IFRAME>, <FRAME>, <APPLET>, <AUDIO>, <VIDEO>, <NOSCRIPT>,` and `<IMG>` elements, as well as
>     webbugs
> - ability to block unwanted content (MVPS HOSTS, hpHOSTS (ad / tracking servers only), Peter Lowe's HOSTS Project,
>     MalwareDomainList.com, and DNS-BH – Malware Domain Blocklist are
>     integrated!)
> - ability to block click-through referrer data
> - "intuitive" icon that changes based on whether or not a page is whitelisted/blacklisted/bypassed
> - shows number of blocked/removed items in toolbar
> - shows blocked/allowed items in tab details popup (along with item type)
> - bulk import domains into whitelist and blacklist
> - option to temporarily allow a page/temporarily allow all blocked items
> - choose the default mode (Block All or Allow All)
> - option to preserve same-domain elements
> - option to disable automatic refresh of pages after whitelisting/blacklisting/temp. bypassing a page

**EDIT:** It now takes advantage of the new Content Blocking API in Chrome 17 to block accurately and very, very fast. The above feature set is old, BTW, but I can't be bothered to update it. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Something a little different from NoScript but may be of interest: [HTTP Switchboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-switchboard/mghdpehejfekicfjcdbfofhcmnjhgaag) allows you to block resources from loading, based on their URL and content-type.  ([Github repository](https://github.com/gorhill/httpswitchboard))

**Update: HTTP Switchboard has been replaced by [uMatrix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf?hl=en) (advanced) and [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) (simple).**  Thanks to [Quinn Comendant](https://superuser.com/users/237155/quinn-comendant) for the links.

[image]

I found it in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/670214/how-can-i-disable-html5-content-in-popular-browsers-like-firefox-and-chrome#671762)

Alternatively, to blacklist known trackers and widgets, you can try [Ghostery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij).  But that does not address the OP's desire, which was to block all Javascript until whitelisted.

Comment: This plugin is just pure awesomeness.

Comment: this plugin has now been split into umatrix and ublock

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [response](http://hackademix.net/2009/12/10/why-chrome-has-no-noscript/) from the NoScript developer as to why NoScript has not been ported to Chrome:

> The reason is very simple: Chrome is still
>   lacking the required infrastructure for
>   selective script disablement and object
>   blocking.

As a result, you can either [block ads](https://superuser.com/questions/8365/noscript-plugin-for-google-chrome/8367#8367) or [turn off all scripting/plugins](https://superuser.com/questions/8365/noscript-plugin-for-google-chrome/9597#9597) - there is no way to white list some sites for scripting/plugins and block others.

Answer (score 8):

There's a great extension called [NotScripts](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/odjhifogjcknibkahlpidmdajjpkkcfn?hl=en)
that is based on FF NoScripts

Answer (score 6):

You can use a startup parameter for your shortcut to block java, java script, images, and plugins by appending one of the following to the end of your google chrome shortcut:

Java : "-disable-java"

Java script : "-disable-javascript"

Plugins : "-disable-plugins"

Images : "-disable-images"

Taken from Lifehacker [here](http://lifehacker.com/5045904/the-power-users-guide-to-google-chrome).

Comment: Outdated. New mechanisms have come out in the Settings/Options menu.