# Ad-Block for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, adblock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get Adblock functionality in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1589/is-it-possible-to-get-adblock-functionality-in-google-chrome)

Looking for an AdBlock replacement for Chrome, I found [AdSweep](http://www.adsweep.org/), which is no longer maintained. Any alternatives?

Comment: Problem is, it's not in Google's interest, being an advertiser, to have an ad blocker in its browser.

Comment: True, but don't Google have a plugin architecture?

Comment: An extension system is being developed, and yes, they are considering ad blocking to be a valid and important use case: http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/extension-manifesto (see under "use cases" -> "content filtering")

Comment: Duplicate? 'Is it possible to get Adblock functionality in Google Chrome?', http://superuser.com/questions/1589/is-it-possible-to-get-adblock-functionality-in-google-chrome

Comment: Right, let's close it.

Answer (score 3):

See [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/8365/noscript-plugin-for-google-chrome/8367#8367) to [NoScript plugin for Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/8365/noscript-plugin-for-google-chrome):

> Check out Privoxy. Lifehacker has a [great guide](http://lifehacker.com/5046529/how-to-block-ads-in-google-chrome) on how to set it up.
>
> Privoxy supports stripping ads, Javascript and nasty pieces of HTML, as well as string-replacement for any web browser. I have used it in the past and I did not notice a speed difference.

Answer (score 2):

Check [**Chrome Beta Adblock extension**](http://www.neowin.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=750116)

Answer (score 1):

SWWare Iron is a build of Chrome that includes an ad blocker.

http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php

It also includes more recent versions of Webkit and the Javascript engine than the shipping version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider running [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) locally to do the filtering.