# How to block access to resources on external domain?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, sandbox

For example I'm browsing www.example.com

At some point, some Javascript is fetched from another domain.

I would like to sandbox example.com. Anything that is not hosted on example.com should be silently dropped. I can't find the correct keyword for this kind of behavior.

Comment: don't know, but two thoughts that don't quite do it. a)the hosts file - but that won't 'cos it would block everything and you'd have to know the domain to block beforehand in order to use the hosts file for that b)privoxy can filter things out but last time I checked, it didn't work with https and i'm not sure what filter would do it and it slows browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Chrome, you should check out [Scriptsafe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptsafe/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf), [Blocksite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh) and [Privoxy](http://lifehacker.com/5046529/how-to-block-ads-in-google-chrome), as per [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/8365/is-there-a-noscript-alternative-for-google-chrome).

For Firefox, [Noscript](http://noscript.net/) should satisfy all your needs in this case.

Comment: Very incomplete answer. In all these examples you mention are you not able to show the setting you suggest he uses?  And I know that for one of your solutions - privoxy a)when I tried it a few years back, it didn't work with https  b)what action or filter would do the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlockSite add on for doing this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh?hl=en

Comment: No. I don't want to block the target domain. I want to restrict the origin domain.